# Showing $[H_1 \times K_1, H \times K] = [H_1, H] \times [K_1, K].$

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

Let $G=H \times K$ where $H$ and $K$ are groups, $H_1 \le H, K_1 \le K$. Using the fact that $[(h_1,k_1),(h,k)] = ([h_1,h],[k_1,k])$ I could prove that $$[H_1 \times K_1, H \times K] \subseteq [H_1,H] \times [K_1,K].  \tag{1}$$ But I haven't been able to prove the reverse inclusion.

The difficulty is that the right side in $(1)$ is $\langle [h_1,h]: h_1 \in H_1, h \in H\rangle \times \langle [k_1,k]: k_1 \in K_1, k \in K\rangle$, that is it is of the form $\langle A\rangle \times \langle B\rangle,$ where $A$ is a subset of $H$ and $B$ is a subset of $K$.

> How could I prove the reverse inclusion?

Comment: Please use `$\langle A\rangle$` for $\langle A\rangle$.

Comment: It suffices to show that every element of a generating side the right hand side is an element of the left hand side. So it is enough to show that every element of the form $([a,b],[c,d])$ with $a\in H_1$, $b\in H$, $c\in K_1$, and $d\in K$, lies in $[H_1\times K_1,H\times K]$.

Comment: Thanks. Notation: $\langle [h_1,h] \rangle$ will stand for $\langle \{[h_1,h]: h_1 \in H_1, h \in H\}$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I have not enough space for my answer in the comments window. Notation: $\langle [h_1,h] \rangle$ will stand for $\langle \{[h_1,h]: h_1 \in H_1, h \in H\} \rangle$. Let $L = [H_1 \times K_1, H \times K]$.                  You say it is enough to show that $([h_1,h],[k_1,k])$ lies in $L$. But that proves that $\langle ([h_1,h],[k_1,k]) \rangle$ lies in $L$. Instead I need to prove that $\langle [h_1,h] \rangle \times \langle [k_1,k] \rangle$ lies in $L$.

I found two ways to prove the reverse inclusion. (a) To work with the internal direct product. So $G$ is now the internal direct product of its subgroups $H$ and $K$, $G = HK$. And I have to prove that, if $H_1 \le H$ and $K_1 \le K$ (I don't know if this condition is necessary) then $[H_1,H][K_1,K] \subseteq [H_1 K_1,HK] =: L$. But $h_1 \in H_1K_1$ and $h \in HK$. So $[h_1,h] \in L$ for all $h_1$ and $h$ and hence $\langle [h_1,h]\rangle \le L$. Similarly $\langle [k_1,k]\rangle \le L$ and the inclusion is proved.

(b) $\langle [h_1,h]\rangle \times 1 = \langle ([h_1,h],1)\rangle = \langle [(h_1,1),(h,1)]\rangle \le L$. Similarly $1 \times \langle [k_1,k]\rangle \le L$. From which I infer $\langle [h_1,h]\rangle \times \langle [k_1,k]\rangle \le L$. That is $[H_1,H] \times [K_1,K] \le L$.

Comment: What I said that it is enough to show that for **every** choice of $h$, $h_1$ in $H$ asnd $k$, $k_1\in K$, you have $([h_1,h],[k_1,k])\in L$. That’s not what you seem to have understood me to say, and proving this *does* suffice. For one thing, it would establish your statement (b), by picking $k=k_1=1$ with arbitrary $h,h_1$, and by picking $h=h_1=1$ with arbitrary k=k_1$. So your interpretation of what I said is incorrect.

Comment: I beg your pardon. Well, I finally could prove the inclusion by using two facts. (a) $[(h_1,k_1),(h,k)] = ([h_1,h],[k_1,k])$.                                                                                                    (b) $<(a,b): a \in A, b \in B> = <A> \times <B>$ for any $A,B$subsets of $G$. Which is easily proved using the definition of $<A>$ as the set of all words on $A$. Thanks again for your reply.